# json Как запустить цикл если в массив разделяет [ ] квадратные скобки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Прошу помощи и подсказки.

Пишу скрипт вывода данных из json в html, не могу произвести цикл их списка.
Мой пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // var productId = '200299818';
    var jsonlink = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/synapse3/JetJson/main/test.json';


        $.getJSON(jsonlink, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i){
            $('#test1').append('<div class="frame">' + data.products[0].product_field_values[0].id + '</div>');
          });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span>test1 :</span>
    <div id="test1"></div>
  </div>
```

Как видим, я на переменную product_field_values указываю [0] - то есть значение берется только из первого строки, а как сделать что бы значение брались и из последующих.

--- И почему в моем случае цикл показывает только 2 строки, хотя в моем json'e их 6

То есть, как миновать или проходить квадратные скобки в цикле, или я не правильно думаю, помогите пожалуйста кодом

Большое спасибо

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/qBqvLzK - вот так и дальше по иерархии

Comment: дальнейший перебор будет удобнее на for-in ну и в принципе на forEach тоже не хило

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
      $.getJSON(jsonlink, function(data) {
        data.products.forEach(item=>{
           $('#test1').append('<div class="frame">' + item.product_field_values[0].id + '</div>');
        }); 
      })
```

Comment: так, только первое значение получаю из всего массива

Comment: @TileaWebsite далее по аналогии. Каждый массив перебираете. У меня ведь нет данных